# Prove that if $g\circ f$ is a quotient map then $g$ is a quotient map.

Tags: general-topology, functions, solution-verification, quotient-spaces

This is a question on a homework for a topology course.

Let $f:X\twoheadrightarrow Y$ and $g:Y\twoheadrightarrow Z$ be continuous surjections. Prove that if $g\circ f$ is a quotient map, then $g$ is a quotient map.

Proof. Since $g$ is a continuous surjection, to show $g$ is a quotient map it suffices to show that a set $W\subseteq Z$ is open if and only if $g^{-1}(W)$ is open in $Y$. Let $W$ be an open subset of $Z$. Since $g$ is continuous, then $g^{-1}(W)$ is open in $Y$. Conversely, let $g^{-1}(W)$ be open in $Y$, and then by the continuity of $f$ we have that $f^{-1}(g^{-1}(W))$ is open in $X$. Since $g\circ f$ is a quotient map, thus $W$ is open in $Z$. $\Box$

Is this correct?

Comment: This looks good to me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct.

Let me make a remark on the definition of a *quotient map*.

If you understand a *map* to be a *continuous function*, then a surjective map $g : Y \to Z$ is a quotient map provided
$$\forall W \subset Z : g^{-1}(W) \text{ open in } Y  \implies W \text{ open in } Z . \tag{1}$$
The reverse implication $W \text{ open in } Z \implies g^{-1}(W) \text{ open in } Y$ is automatically satisfied because $g$ is continuous (as you observed in your proof); it is therefore unnecessary to include it in the definition.

On the other hand, if you interpret *map* as a synonym for *function*, then you must require
$$\forall W \subset Z : g^{-1}(W) \text{ open in } Y  \Longleftrightarrow W \text{ open in } Z \tag{2}$$
because continuity is  not automatically covered by $(1)$.